# atomic indexOf bug with searchElement derived from video currentTime

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, indexof

I am confused by the unpredictable results of array indexOf in current release Chrome 37.0.2062.94 on a mac.  It appears that array.indexOf is not working *sometimes* when the searchElement is created using a video element's timecode.

To see the error, let the video play for a few seconds and then playback will stop when the array.indexOf error occurs.  It seems that this is a bug in an atomic operation?  Is there something I am overlooking?

Here is a bin http://jsbin.com/lobifotoxeyi/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<video id="video">
    <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>

var trippedBugTimes = 0;

function tick() {
    var nowTime = document.getElementById('video').currentTime;

    //this seems to be crucial... if val is just assigned 100, we don't get the bug.
    var val = (nowTime - nowTime) + 100;

    //this also seems to be important.. we cannot put val in as the sole member of the array, it has to be a different variable.
    var a = [100];
    var idx = a.indexOf( val );
    if (idx == -1) {
        console.log( "*bug*", 
            "idx ->", idx, 
            "val -> ", val, 
            "a ->", a, 
            "a[0] === val ->", a[0] === val, 
            "typeof a[0] ->", typeof a[0], 
            "typeof val ->", typeof val );

        document.getElementById('video').pause();

        trippedBugTimes += 1;
    }

    if (trippedBugTimes < 100) {
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
    else {
        console.log( "Bug reporting complete" );
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(tick);

setTimeout( document.getElementById('video').play(), 1000 );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I've posted a bug report to the chrome team: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407946

Comment: what is the idea behind `(nowTime - nowTime) + 100;` instead of writing just `100`?

Comment: i dont quite know why you would subtract the current time from the current time? what if this would be 0? what is the purpose?

Comment: ok i figured `var val = nowTime - nowTime + 100;` is always 100, but sometimes the .indexOf would fail, now I get you. this is interesting.

Comment: but still, why would you need to do `nowtime - nowtime`? what is the actual calculation here?

Comment: The video will pause when it is not able to find searchElement 100 in an array with only one element, 100.  The creation of the searchElement is somewhat contrived (timecode-timecode)+100, but this on purpose to demonstrate the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments under the original post, this bug was reported to the chromium team.  It has since been fixed (although there is no known easy way for determining if the bug is in your blink implementation or not...)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407946